# Mule same Payload is displaying in different format in logger for different condition

Tags: xml, xpath, mule, mule-studio

I have a mule flow :-

```
<jdbc-ee:connector name="Database_Global" dataSource-ref="DB_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database">
 <jdbc-ee:query key="UpdateQuerySOAPRequest" value="UPDATE getData SET ID=#[xpath('//v1:Id').text], NAME=#[xpath('//v1:Name').text], AGE=#[xpath('//v1:Age').text], DESIGNATION = #[xpath('//v1:Designation').text] where ID=#[xpath('//v1:Id').text]"/>
</jdbc-ee:connector>
<flow name="NodeNameFlow" doc:name="NodeNameFlow" initialState="started">
               <file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="File_Input" doc:name="File"  path="E:\backup\test">
                        <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="XMLRequest.xml" caseSensitive="false"/>
                </file:inbound-endpoint>
             <splitter evaluator="xpath" expression="//v1:updateDataRequest" doc:name="Splitter_For_MultipleSameNodes"/>
            <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer name="DomToXmlSOAPUpdate2" doc:name="Dom To XmlSOAPUpdate"/>
            <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="UpdateQuerySOAPRequest" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="Database_Global" doc:name="Database (JDBC)"/>  

             <choice doc:name="Choice">
             <when expression="#[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UPDATE_COUNT']==0]"> <!-- If not updated -->
            <logger message="Updated #[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UPDATE_COUNT']] rows... Failed!!! No rows were Updated" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
              </when>
            <otherwise> <!-- if updated -->
            <set-payload value="Updated Successfully !!!" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
             </otherwise>
              </choice>      

               <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"></mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer>
                    <async doc:name="Async_Database_Response_in_File">
                        <logger message="Request *************************** #[payload:java.lang.String]  *************************" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

                        <file:outbound-endpoint path="E:\backup\test" outputPattern="SimpleResponse.txt" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" connector-ref="File_Global"/>
                    </async> 

             </flow>
```

Now you can see It is taking an xml file as input, splitting it and updating the database based on ID and at the end it is logging the payload in an outbound file ..  .. if It is able to update the data base successfully it is able to display the payload in the logger `<logger message="Request *************************** #[payload:java.lang.String]  *************************" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>` at the end in correct way like:-

```
 org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Request ***************************<string> <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <v1:updateDataRequest>
             <v1:Id>1</v1:Id>
             <v1:Name>BnnnnnnBB !!!!!</v1:Name>
             <v1:Age>66</v1:Age>
             <v1:Designation>EEEEEE</v1:Designation>
          </v1:updateDataRequest>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope> </string> *************************
```

But if it is not able to update the Database based on ID it will display the payload like the following :-

```
 org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Request *************************** <string>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
&lt;v1:updateDataRequest xmlns:v1=&quot;http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1&quot;&gt;
         &lt;v1:Id&gt;1&lt;/v1:Id&gt;
         &lt;v1:Name&gt;BnnnnnnBB !!!!!&lt;/v1:Name&gt;
         &lt;v1:Age&gt;66&lt;/v1:Age&gt;
         &lt;v1:Designation&gt;EEEEEE&lt;/v1:Designation&gt;
      &lt;/v1:updateDataRequest&gt;</string>  *************************
```

... 
So my question is why it is display the same payload in this format if it is not able to update .... any suggestion .. Do.. I need to transform the payload in any format ... any suggestion ????

Comment: Your question would be so much better if you would format the flow XML properly...

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your response .. This is actually a small part of my flow .. What I need to ask is that :- The payload format in logger is different after it comes from the first condition of choice i.e :- <when expression="#[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UPDATE_COUNT']==0]"> <!-- If not updated -->
            <logger message="Updated #[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UPDATE_COUNT']] rows... Failed!!! No rows were Updated" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

Comment: Ugh, XML in comments is even worse :( Bit of advice, next time you post XML in your question, indent it appropriately so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI the MEL syntax for `#[payload:java.lang.String]` is `#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]`

There's something not logical in the flow: in case of success `set-payload` sets the payload to a non-XML string (i.e `"Updated Successfully !!!"`).

But then, after `choice` the `mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer` kicks-in and tries to transfrom this random String into XML, which can't really work. You need to fix this.

Comment: Cool, glad it was the issue!

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up with `#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]` instead of `#[payload:java.lang.String]` as David suggested and also stored the payload in a flow variable just before the DB component and set it into the payload since the payload was breaking .... it worked !!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
FYI the MEL syntax for #[payload:java.lang.String] is #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]

There's something not logical in the flow: in case of success set-payload sets the payload to a non-XML string (i.e "Updated Successfully !!!").

But then, after choice the mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer kicks-in and tries to transfrom this random String into XML, which can't really work. You need to fix this.
```